# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'function' objects - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have this function, which I'm migrating from v8 to v10

```
def search_partner_seniat(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Check vat of the partner and update iva rate
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    this = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)[0]
    su_obj = self.env('seniat.url')
    rp_obj = self.env('res.partner')
    vat = this.vat.upper()
    res = {'name': _('The requested contributor does not exist'),
           'vat_subjected': False, 'vat': vat, 'wh_iva_agent': False,
           'wh_iva_rate': 0.0}

    if 'VE' in vat:
        vat = vat[2:]

    if rp_obj.check_vat_ve(vat, context=context):
        res = su_obj._dom_giver(cr, uid, vat, context)
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, res)

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'search.info.partner.seniat',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_id': this.id,
        'views': [(False, 'form')],
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

How can I return this on the new API fashion?

This is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/server.py", line 246, in app
return self.app(e, s)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
result = handler(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 1306, in __call__
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 1280, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 588, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 1454, in dispatch
odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/__init__.py", line 55, in registry
return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 55, in __new__
return cls.new(db_name)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 333, in load_modules
force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 235, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 135, in load_module_graph
registry.setup_models(cr, partial=True)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 296, in setup_models
model._setup_complete()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 2860, in _setup_complete
cls._init_constraints_onchanges()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 652, in _init_constraints_onchanges
cls.pool._sql_error[cls._table + '_' + key] = msg
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'function' objects
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try su_obj = self.pool.get('seniat.url') and rp_obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use the new API, then migrate the code complete. For you method it should be:

```py
@api.multi
def search_partner_seniat(self):
    """ Check vat of the partner and update iva rate
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    vat = self.vat.upper()
    res = {
        'name': _('The requested contributor does not exist'),
        'vat_subjected': False,
        'vat': vat,
        'wh_iva_agent': False,
        'wh_iva_rate': 0.0
    }

    if 'VE' in vat:
        vat = vat[2:]

    # assumption: both methods in new api style
    if self.env['res.partner'].check_vat_ve(vat):  # check_vat_ve() should be @api.model
        res = self.env['seniat.url']._dom_giver(vat)  # _dom_giver() should be @api.model
    self.write(res)

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'search.info.partner.seniat',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_id': self.id,
        'views': [(False, 'form')],
        'target': 'new',
    }
```